# PHP Upload CSV aborted after 200 rows

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I have a total of 2000 rows in my csv file. I noticed that it stops the upload around 280-300. I am using Laravel for my application.

I am using fgetcsv() and my code is like this.

```
if (($handle = fopen($destinationPath . $filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
          while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 3000, ",")) !== FALSE)  {           
           if($row == 1){ $row++; continue; }
           }
        }
```

Inside the while loop has a lot of conditional statements, insert query and update query.

What causes this bug? In my localhost, it is properly working, but in my server it isn't. Here's the specs of my shared hosting:

[image: Server]

What should be the solution for this? Thanks.

UPDATE: I tried adding the `set_time_limit(0);` then tried uploading the csv. Then I tried to use stopwatch and it exactly stops at 00:02:03.02 . That means it stops around 2 minutes.

Comment: Are you getting an error? that should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I get redirected to my error 404 page. Hold on, I will try to activate the debug mode.

Comment: Try `set_time_limit(0)` at the top of your script for testing only if that works set it to some safe value equal to time you can guess for csv processing

Answer (score 1):

Your php.ini settings looks fine. It is probably because of the your web server's(nginx, apache, litespeed etc.) settings.

If it is nginx, increasing the "fastcgi_read_timeout" will fix your issue. As it is a shared server I think you need to contact your hosting provider.

ps: this message suits for a comment but I am not privileged for posting a comment.

Comment: Don't try to get around the reputation restrictions by posting comments as answers. Once you have sufficient reputation, you can post comments.